# Datatable with long data rows on small RAM memory

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, serverside-javascript

I am using a datatable with too much data rows, in a 4go ram computer it works greate, but in 2Go ram it take too much time to show results, what can i do, currently i am making my datatables like this

```
  <script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var table = jQuery('#example').dataTable({
             "bProcessing": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "data.php",
             "sServerMethod": "POST",
              "bPaginate":true,
              "scrollX": true,
              "sPaginationType":"numbers",
              "iDisplayLength": 10...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to use "deferred rendering" - so only those rows requested are sent/loaded. There's an example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html) on the DataTables site.